# Preserve instance of class in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Is actually possible to do something like this?

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UbiSharedService {

    private _ubiData: object = {};

    private $$instance: UbiSharedService;

    constructor() {

    }

    public setData(key: string, data: any) {
        this._ubiData[key] = data;
    }

    public getData(key: string): any {
        return this._ubiData[key];
    }

    public popData(key: string): any {
        return delete this._ubiData[key];
    }

    public getInstance(): UbiSharedService {
        if (!!this.$$instance && this.$$instance instanceof UbiSharedService) {
            //NOOP
        }
        else {
            this.$$instance = new UbiSharedService();
        }

        return this.$$instance;
    }


}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The standard behavior of injecting services injects them as a singleton. The state of a singleton will preserve throughout the lifetime of the application. In the case of an Angular application it will preserve as long as the browser window is open.

Comment: I'm trying to read/write data from multiple components. But I'm having some issues finding the way of using this methods from the components...

Comment: So you are trying to use the service in components and call the methods of this service, e.g. setData or getData?

Comment: I'd like to call setData from A.component and read the same data from B.component :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `$$instance` and instead inject the service into the components that need it using the constructor.

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService,
                private productParameterService: ProductParameterService) { }
```

Then the component can access the service methods using the `productService` or `productParameterService` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following documentation from Angular to learn how to use services to share data between unrelated components:
https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services.

You can inject services in components by adding them to the constructor of the component:

```
constructor(
    private ubiSharedService: UbiSharedService
) { 
   // You can now call in the methods of ubiSharedService
   // e.g.: this.ubiSharedService.setData('key', { value: 'Value' });
}
```

Comment: This is my same suggestion ... just with a better example showing *your* particular scenario.

Comment: Yes I understood that. In fact I'll pick your answer since you answered first :)

Comment: @DeborahK please update your answer for others that come here. Include the link to the singleton services angular documentation page.